# How to solve the console window blocking?

Tags: windows, shell, monitor, windows-console

I ran a script file under Windows, and it was executed indefinitely, but when I put the mouse in the console window, the script blocked. How can I prevent it from blocking?

It should be a monitoring script. I don't want interactive events, and I don't want the program to be blocked.

[image: Screenshot of a console window with a selection]

Comment: Writing to the console will block if there's an active text selection. This can happen accidentally with a mouse click if the console's quick-edit mode is enabled. To avoid this, run your script using a .lnk shortcut that has quick-edit mode disabled in the properties.

Comment: @eryksun: I recommend that you turn your comment to an answer. AFIK, this is the only reliable way to get the desired effect. An alternative would be to start the console minimized, but you don't have the guarantee that someone restores it. Of course if the Windows console is not really needed, an option would be to use Cygwin with the mintty console. This is what I generally use.